# Numerical values associated with Drop Down options

Tags: matlab, validation, user-interface, drop-down-menu, matlab-app-designer

So I am creating an app to work out a value based on a series of variables. The variables are:

- Gender
- Age
- Weight
- Creatinine

Here's what the app looks like:

[image: Showing the UI off]

In order to simplify the process somewhat I decided to make the gender selection a dropdown menu, this has caused me some issues since I have it setup like so:

[image: Drop Down properties]

And the maths associated with the button looks like so:

```
  function CalculateButtonPushed(app, event)
            gender = app.PatientGenderDropDown.Value ;
            age = app.PatientAgeEditField.Value ;
            weight = app.LeanBodyWeightEditField.Value ;
            serum = app.SerumCreatinineEditField.Value ;
            final = (gender*(age)*weight) / (serum) ;
            app.ResultEditField.Value = final ;
        end
    end
```

Running this gives the following error:

> Error using
> matlab.ui.control.internal.model.AbstractNumericComponent/set.Value
> (line 104) 'Value' must be numeric, such as 10.

As far as I am aware, the values I input into `ItemsData` are numeric values. Have I missed something or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How are you initializing your variables? javascript figures out it's type the first time it's assigned a value so var gender = "" would make gender a string. var gender = 0 would make gender an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint in the offending file on the appropriate line (by running the below code),

```
dbstop in uicomponents\+matlab\+ui\+control\+internal\+model\AbstractNumericComponent.m at 87
```

you could see the following in your workspace, after clicking the button:

[image: workspace snapshot]

There are two separate problems here, both of which can be identified by looking at the `newValue` validation code (appearing in `AbstractNumericComponent.m`):

```
% newValue should be a numeric value.
% NaN, Inf, empty are not accepted
validateattributes(...
    newValue, ...
    {'numeric'}, ...
    {'scalar', 'real', 'nonempty'} ...
    );
```

Here are the issues:

1. The new value is a vector ***of `NaN`***. 
   The reason for this is in this line:

   ```
   final = (gender*(age)*weight) / (serum) ;
   ```

   where `serum` has a value of `0` - so this is the first thing you should take care of.
2. The new value is ***a vector*** of `NaN`. 
   This is a separate problem, since the `set.Value` function (which is implicitly called when you assign something into the `Value` field), is expecting a **scalar**. This happens because `gender` is a `1x4 char array` - so it's treated as 4 separate numbers (i.e. the assumption about `ItemsData` being a numeric is incorrect). The simplest solution in this case would be to  `str2double` it before use. Alternatively, store the data in another location
   (such as a private attribute of the figure), **making sure** it's numeric.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Although I didn't use your method specifically I did find that converting the number to a double somewhere else worked. Thank you again for your help!